# Matching attribute values using wildcards with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, cheerio

I have a selector like this:

```
$('link[href="../../../target/test/css/index.css"]')
```

The portion after `../target/` can be anything.  How do I specify wildcards in jquery?  This is approximately what I'm looking for in terms of a globbing pattern:

```
$('link[href="../../../target/**/*.css"]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't wildcards *per se*, but you can combine the [starts with (^=)](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [ends with ($=)](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selectors to achieve the effect you are looking for:

```
$('link[href^="../../../target/"][href$=".css"]');
```

jQuery is equipped with a number of useful attribute selectors that can help for problems like this-- you can check them out at https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/.